# Production redirect loop error on root domain, but not with www

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'd like when a user types the domain YOURSITE.com to not go into a loop and crash. I've searched for answers for a couple days now and can't seem to find the exact one.

> Error from chrome: This webpage has a redirect loop - The webpage at http://YOURSITE.com/ >has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third->party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and >not a problem with your computer.

#### Background:

Rails 3.2.14 App with Ruby 2.0.0

Domain bought with godaddy

Hosting on Heroku with both domains setup www.YOURSITE.com and YOURSITE.com
Using AWS with route 53 and S3.

Let me know what relevant code you need to help or if this is something that is being caused by AWS or the like. I've tried an reversed several different things via my code, but can't seem to find anything that works.

Comment: `wget --server-response http://yoursite.com -O -` *should* make the problem obvious to you, because you will see what machines are being hit and how they are responding and inappropriately sending redirects.

Comment: If the "real" site is on www, then you may be using an S3 bucket to redirect the bare domain to the www... but actually have it redirecting to itself, instead.

Answer (score 1):

you should log into your Heroku dashboard, click on the app and then click on the "Production Check" button. This will help you check for DNS issues among other.

Check your DNS Zone file with godaddy. How are you redirecting the sub domain www to the host domain?

On your rails app, how is your route.rb file handling the incoming traffic? do you have any redirection there?

Hope that helps..

Comment: Galuga, I think I figured it out and it wasn't anything in my rails app thank god, it was all configuration between heroku and AWS. I'm going to post it in an answer to my own question. 
I did have redirection in my routes but it was root: to => 'home#index', but that shouldn't have been affecting anything

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good write up that goes through configuration settings between AWS, the domain registrar (in my case godaddy), and heroku here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53#naked-root-domain  I used this originally when I set up my site.

I wish I could say I know what the problem was, but I'm not totally sure what it was. My guess is that it had to do with APEX domains being unsupported by AWS and/or Heroku, and therefore I needed not to try to redirect. Here's the settings that worked for me:

Godaddy domain mysite.com, transferred my DNS stuff to AWS (I had done that prior to the problem)

Heroku: you can either use the CL or you can access the settings for your app online. In either situation I set up my domains to be mysite.com and www.mysite.com

AWS: This is a little trickier. You need to make sure the settings for Route 53 and S3 are exactly like in the tutorial link above. Your mysite.com bucket in S3 **must** redirect to www.mysite.com.

This isn't ideal and there are probably ways to get around this using different companies for hosting/DNS services, but with the Heroku/AWS combo this is what I had to do to stop the redirect loop.